# Why does AbstractSet not include union and intersection?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, abstract-class, typing

Is there a documented reason for excluding `union` and `intersection` from the defining methods of `abc.Set` and thereby from `typing.AbstractSet`? As a result, I often have to use `Union[Set,FrozenSet]` where I expected to be able to use `AbstractSet`. This is particularly puzzling given that the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Set) suggest giving preference to `AbstractSet` for argument type annotations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Authoratative Source

[PEP 3119](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) defines the abstract bases classes.

The overall design goal was for "the ABCs define a *minimal* set of methods that establish the characteristic behavior of the type. Code that discriminates objects based on their ABC type can trust that those methods will always be present."

The specific rationale for the minimal *abc.Set* API is mentioned only in passing, "the issubset and issuperset methods found on the set type in Python 2 are not supported, as these are mostly just aliases for __le__ and __ge__", and "this ABC does not provide the named methods present on the built-in concrete set type that perform (almost) the same operations."

Comment: Thanks! (Of course the standard aliases exist because they make code readable.)

Answer (score -1):

`collections.abc.Set` only includes the operator forms of those operations, `|` and `&`. Otherwise, the interface wouldn't cover the set-like objects returned by `dict.keys` and `dict.items`, which don't have `union` or `intersection` methods.

Comment: This seems to beg the question.  If we really want to be able to write `d1 | d2` and refer to it as a dictionary union, then we should also be able to spell it more explicitly as `d1.union(d2)`. And similarly for the keys view.  
(I'll admit that I'm not a big fan of PEP 584.)

Comment: @Alan: Dict unions are a separate thing. I'm talking about dict views, which predate `collections.abc`. Dict unions have no bearing on `collections.abc.Set`.

Comment: I'm confused. In `abc`, yes `KeysView` and for some strange reason `ItemsView` inherit from `Set`. But that if that is desirable, and if sets naturally come with a concept of union and intersection (don't they??), then these too should support union and intersection. Instead, `abc.Set` was deprived of `union` and `intersection`, which seems bizarre -- although, see the discussion above. (Indeed, how can one determine from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) that annotating with `typing.MutableSet` is enough to type check a call to `union` or `intersection`.)